# Hide admin bar on all pages except homepage

Tags: admin-bar

I am trying to hide WordPress admin bar from all pages except the home page.

I added the following CODE in the theme's `functions.php` file, but it hides the admin bar on all pages:

```
if ( ! is_single() ) {
   add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_false' );
}
```

I want it to appear only on the homepage and to be hidden everywhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use conditional tag inside function hooked to `show_admin_bar` filter.

```
add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', 'show_adminbar_on_homepage_only', 20 );
function show_adminbar_on_homepage_only()
{
     return is_user_logged_in() && is_front_page();
}
```

Comment: this does the trick to show the admin bar on the homepage only, however, when i log out the bar box is stil visible on the homepage, though there is no user data on it anymore

Comment: @Badan It should work properly now.

Comment: now it is hidden everywhere again.

Comment: I removed the is_home() check and now it is working like a charm! But i do not undestand how it works. Can you provide brief explanation?

Comment: The `show_admin_bar` filter hook allows you to change display status of the admin bar for front side, if function attached to this hook returns TRUE, admin bar will be visible. Conditional tags `is_home()` and `is_front_page()` (similar, but slightly different, [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) you can read more about them) check whether the currently displayed page is the home page, and the `is_user_logged_in()` - as the name suggests. It's strange that  you have to remove `is_home()`, I checked and `is_user_logged_in() && (is_home() || is_front_page())` works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a priority issue, meaning that some plugin / theme function is overriding the admin bar behaviour. Try something like this:

```
if (!is_home() && !is_front_page()){
   add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false', 999);
}
```

If this work, let's try to understand which plugins are and assign the right priority, like a lower 99 or whatever.

Comment: i tried with the priority but it is still not working.. maybe i should put the code in a different file, not in functions.php?

Comment: let's try this, put in `functions.php` the raw function `show_admin_bar(false);` and let me know.

Comment: i put show_admin_bar(false); it hides the admin bar everywhere.

Comment: Let's try now with just the `add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');` without conditionals and let me know.

Comment: both options work for all pages

Comment: Ah sorry I had to go away! I've seen you found the solution anyways. Happy for that!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a better way to do it that improves on the existing answers:

```
add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', function ( $show ) {

    if ( is_front_page() ) {
        return false;
    }

    return $show;
}, 50 );
```

Unlike the other code examples given, this snippet will only change the admin bar visibility if currently viewing the front page. Otherwise, it will use whatever the default is set to. This removes the need to account for different cases where the user is not logged in.

Answer (score -1):

You should check if page is home page and/or front page. 
`is_front_page()` returns true when viewing the site's front page (blog posts index or a static page), `is_home()` returns true when viewing the blog posts index.
try as below,

```
if (!is_home() && !is_front_page()){
   add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');
}
```

or

```
if (!is_home()){
   add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');
}
```

Comment: i tried this but it is also not working..

Comment: try with `else (is_home()){
   add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_true');
}`

Comment: still hiding it everywhere..